# Monotouch bindings with C and C++ calls

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind a third party library that makes calls to c++ code and c code. I was wondering if there's anything different I need to add in the additional monotouch arguments to make it work correctly.

In the implementation instructions we received for the library (for native iOS), it states that the library contains C and C++ files, and to let the XCode compiler recognize all the source files, the file that contains the controller for the library must have the file extension .mm

It also said to link all the Objective-C classes in the static library (from what i gathered, in monotouch this means to use the -all_load flag) and then to set the Other Linker Flags in the build settings to -ObjC.

The last part states that when using XCode 4.5 or above, the compiler options "C++ Language Dialect" and "C++ Standard Library" must be set to "Compiler Default".

I have created the binding just fine and I can access the methods. But some of the callbacks don't return all the data and, even stranger, some of the callbacks on the delegate object trigger multiple times. I assume this is because of the C and C++ code in the library and that I havent added all the right flags to the linkwith.cs file in the binding project as well as in the Additional mtouch arguments in the iOS build options.

Are there any special arguments I need to put in the mtouch arguments or the linkwith.cs file to make these bindings work correctly?

Comment: In general if you don't get the right mtouch/linkwith arguments correctly, your project doesn't build, or it crashes at runtime. The behavior you're seeing doesn't quite match that, so I _believe_ that the problem is elsewhere (probably with the bindings themselves). Can you explain exactly what's happening (what's the ObjC API, how did you bind it, what's the behavior you're seeing and what are you expecting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In order to allow your library to execute C++ code, you need to add the `IsCxx=True` flag to your linkwith.cs file. And then in your main project where you're including the binding library, you have to go to the additional mtouch arguments and add `-cxx`

As for the compiler defaults, using the following flag, I was able to make it work:
`-gcc_flags "-lstdc++"`